# Why can't I trigger my Visico strobe and AD600 together with a Godox XPro-C and X1R receiver?

Tags: canon, wireless-flash, godox, triggers

I am using the Godox XPro-C transmitter and can trigger my AD600BM without any problems.

But when I want to trigger my second stribe, a Visico head, cabled to a  Godox X1R receiver, there's a problem.

The settings for ID number, channels, and group seem to be correct. And when I press the test button on the Xpro, both heads fire without any problem.

But when I use the shutter button on the camera, only the AD600BM fires. Furthermore, when I turn off the AD600BM's group on the Xpro trigger and leave the Visico with the X1R receiver active, it does fire.

Both strobes will not fire together simulatneously.

I have tried resetting; with a mirrorless and with a DSLR camera; I've changed groups, ID, and channels. I also tried the Xpro-N for Nikon and it works flawlessly.

Does anybody have a similar problem?

Comment: Try changing the distance setting to 0-30m. Also make sure you do not have Mask or Alt enabled on either unit (causes it to use one flash at a time in sequence); but I think that's unlikely to be the issue, and IDT it's even possible with the X1R.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure, if I understood your setting correctly.

**What I assume**

- It sounds, you have a Godox Xpro Trigger for Canon on your canon camera
- Godox AD 600 BM fires correctly
- You have used Godox X1R receiver and hooked your secondary flash onto that via sync cable
- The secondary flash is not triggered.

**Possible solutions**

- Check that Channel and (if used) ID of the receiver is the same as the sender (as you say, the test button on Xpro fires all flashes, that should be ok)
- Make sure the receiver is on the right group that you want to trigger (as you say, the test button on Xpro fires all flashes, that should be ok)
- If you do a test flash on the Xpro, you should see some reaction on the X1R via LED.
- If you do a test flash via button on the X1R, your secondary flash should fire. Otherwise the pc sync socket might be switched to input, not output mode. Refer to you manual to change that. In worst case, your pc sync cable is defective. As you said, the trigger on the xpro can fire both flashes, that should not be the case. I included it for completeness.
- The Xpro can have some issues when the sender is really close to the receiver. Set the mode to near mode in the Xpro unit: use the distance setting 0-30 meters